# How to change to default value of a base field with odoo

Tags: odoo

On the user creation form, we have a default field named "Contact Creation" defined [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/addons/base/security/base_security.xml#L58). The default value is `True` and I'd like to set as `False` but I don't know how to do.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py#L270 `base.group_partner_manager` group is assigned to user by default when creating a new one.

You can overwrite default as [Alessandro said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34071481/2868531) to a custom method:

```
from openerp import models, fields

class ResUsers(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    def _get_group_custom(self):
        groups = self._get_group()
        try:
           dummy, manager = self.env['ir.model.data'].sudo().get_object_reference('base', 'group_partner_manager')
           groups.remove(manager)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return groups

    groups_id = fields.Many2many(default=_get_group_custom)
```

Comment: It seems like I didn't get the question at all.

Answer (score 3):

The link you provided points to a user group creation. Which is not related to fields.

BTW if you have any field

```
f = fields.Boolean(default=True)
```

and you want to change its default, you just need to inherit the whole model and redefine the very same field

```
f = fields.Boolean(default=False)
```

(leaving other eventual properties undefined)